# Regex to Split Full Name

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am looking for a Regex to be using in my Java app to split Full Name into First & Last Name parts.

The Full Name will always be separated by " " (Space as Delimiter).
some name can consist of Middle Name , But they can be combined with FirstName , i only want to separate Last Name as separate group.

```
For example :
"This is My Fullname"
 LastName = Fullname
 FirstName = This is My
```

So the logic being , anything after Last WhiteSpace is considered as LastName and everything before that as FirstName.

Comment: Just for the record, my legal surname is "Villar Villar" yes, same word, twice, separated by a space, and I live in an English speaking country. Another surname is "De Lorean" which also has a space. You can simply use `fullName.lastIndexOf()` as suggested by WillShackleford, but if I were you I would make sure twice you don't have this issue in your data first.

Comment: What about "This is My Fullname Jr."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seemed to me that regular expressions were not really best for this case.

```
String fullName = "This is My Fullname";
int index = fullName.lastIndexOf(' ');
String lastName = fullName.substring(index+1);
String firstName = fullName.substring(0, index);
```

Comment: Hi will , this work perfect for all my Names , at present very few .But the format should be very similar to existing entries. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use RegEx for this purpose. Just split the string by Spaces and use the last array item as a LastName.

Example

```
String[] parts = string.split(" ");
```

part[parts.length - 1] - will be LastName

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need a "look ahead" approach, as you don't know the number of spaces in your input. The problem is referencing groups with unknown number of items.
E.g. ([^ ]) ([^ ]) ([^ ]) ([^ ]) and referencing $3 and $4 would work in your 4 items string but not with more items. And ([^ ] )*([^ ]) would not be able to reference the groups.

But in that simple case I would say the easiest is to use a String split and take the last 2 items:

```
String inputString = "This is My Fullname";
String[] splitText = inputString.split(" ");
String firstName = splitText[splitText.length-2];
String lastName = splitText[splitText.length-1];
```